# Show that $|f(0)| \le \sqrt{12}$ for the following complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

If $f$ is an analytic function on $D(0\ ;2)$ with $|f(z)| < 4 $ if $\text{Im}(z) \ge 0\ \text{and}\ |z| =1$, and $|f(z)| < 3$ if $\text{Im}(z) <0\ \text{and}\ |z| =1$. How do I show $|f(0)| \le \sqrt{12}\ ?$

Can I use $g(z) = f(z)\cdot f(-z)$ here? I thought of using maximum modulus theorem on $g(z)$ also, but it doesn't seem to work as I need a $a\in D(0\ ;2)$ such that the condition in the theorem is satisfied, I can't see what will be it's ($a'$s) value.  Do I need to calculate the derivative of $g(z)$ and do something with it? How do I proceed? Any ideas/hints?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, duplicate indeed. I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: I found it with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf(0)%7C%20%5Cle%20%5Csqrt%7B12%7D%24&p=1) – see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969 for more information about that search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|g(z)| \leq 12$ whenever $|z|=1$ so MMP implies that $|g(0)| \leq 12$. This means $|f(0)|^{2} \leq 12$ or $|f(0)| \leq \sqrt {12}$.

Comment: should be a comma before "or" to avoid ambiguity